# Update a particular field in the entire django model

Tags: django

I have a model

```
class College(models.Model):
    is_published = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I registered the model in admin.py

```
@admin.register(College)
class CollegeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name')
```

Now I want to have a button on the admin panel, on pressing which I can change the `is_published` field of all the objects in the model to `True`.

I have no idea how should I proceed. Any working code snippet will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [custom admin action](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#adding-actions-to-the-modeladmin) is the perfect tool for this job.

For example (copied almost word for word from the documentation):

```
def publish(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(is_published=True)
publish.short_description = "Mark selected stories as published"

@admin.register(College)
class CollegeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name')
    actions = [publish]
```